# tx_news - OverwriteDemand as Pagetitle

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news

I have an "archive" page with a List View element and a Category Menu
The code below is at the top of the List.html template:

```
<!-- list title --> 
<f:if condition="{news.0.categories}">
    <f:then>
        <f:for each="{news.0.categories}" as="category">
            <n:titleTag>
                <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode><f:translate key="archive" /> - {category.title}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
            </n:titleTag>
            <div class="list-title">
                <h1><f:translate key="archive" /> - {category.title}</h1>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </f:then>
</f:if>
```

Basically setting the Pagetitle to the Category Title displayed in the list.
This works because I am only showing one category at a time.

I have since added this code to the Detail.html template:

```
<!-- Author link -->
<f:if condition="{newsItem.author}">
    <span class="news-list-author">
        <f:link.page title="{newsItem.author}" pageUid="{settings.detailPid}" additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{author: newsItem.author, categories: categories}}}">
            {newsItem.author}
        </f:link.page>
    </span>
</f:if>
```

This sends the user to the same archive page, but now showing all news in ALL categories that belong to the author. This is as desired. However, the Pagetitle is obviously just showing the category title of the first news item.

**QUESTION:** How do I set the Pagetitle to what is "in the OverwriteDemand" so to speak?
(It may be obvious that I do not understand how the OverwriteDemand works)

Answer (score 1):

You have access this in fluid with `{overwriteDemand}`, for testing I propose to use `<f:debug>{overwriteDemand}</f:debug>`.

So if you want to add the author to the title, just use

```
<n:titleTag>
  <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
    {overwriteDemand.author}
  </f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
</n:titleTag>
```

---

However as this can get complicated with a lot of conditions I would rather propose to copy the `TitleTagViewHelper` to your extension, add all arguments you need and do the logic with plain PHP. Of course doing everything in fluid is still fine.